# Javascript pie chart not showing on my page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pie-chart

[Here is my Php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ByEz.png)

[Here is my Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhTl3.png)

[Here is my CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr6KQ.png)

[Here is my current error to my pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F99Wp.png)

Currently i have entered my coding where it should have a pie chart appearing on my webpage however currently i do not see anything except for a colored background according to my CSS code anyone here able to fix the error message in the image?

Comment: Please copy/paste your code and error information into the question _as text_. We cannot edit or run an image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the canvas inside of a

```
<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
```

element otherwise the getContext('2d') function will not work. DOM manipulation can be a bit finnicky